# C program for fetching the date time of centOS server from ubuntu server?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu, centos

I want a C program to fetch the date time of centOS server from Ubuntu server via UDP. I wrote a code which is fetching UTC timestamp which is +06 hours from the actual date time in centOS. NTP is not allowed.

i used setsockopt, getsockopt, sendto & recvfrom for networking.

Port number 1099 & Centos timezone is CST, ubuntu timezone is UTC. Suppose, it is Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:06:25 in Centos then ubuntu is recieving Fri, 28 Nov 2014 09:06:25 i.e. +0600 hrs. Format is UTC timestamp.

Is there any way to fetch the equivalent UTC timestamp of date time in centOS from ubuntu?

I am trying to sync date time of centOS & Ubuntu machine irrespective of timezone.

Please help! Any idea or suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: What port number are you using to communicate with the centOS server?  Also, can you give an example of the timestamp you are receiving, and the format of "the actual date time" you wish to receive?

Comment: @TonyB Port number 1099 & Centos timezone is CST, ubuntu timezone is UTC. Suppose, it is Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:06:25 in Centos then ubuntu is recieving Fri, 28 Nov 2014 09:06:25 i.e. +0600 hrs. Format is 1417165610.

Comment: @KK "Fri, 28 Nov 2014 09:06:25" IS the UTC timestamp of "Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:06:25 CST". What do you really want to do ?

Comment: @nos Hi, timestamp of Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:06:25 is 1417124185. But i am receiving 1417145785 which is timestamp of Fri, 28 Nov 2014 09:06:25. I want the timestamp of centos date time i.e 1417124185 so that i can convert this & set it into ubuntu server.

Comment: Edit your question to show some code and some exchanged data. Work only in UTC time (relative to the epoch, e.g. `time_t`...). Read about [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html) & [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: @KK A unix timestamp is always in UTC, and it does not include timezone information. 1417145785 is the UTC timestamp "Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:06:25" (and 1417145785 is also the CST timestamp "Nov 27 2014 21:36:25"), so that seems to be correct.

Comment: @nos ok! got it. So only option left is deducting the hours according to timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose CenOS CST is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Standard_Time (UTC-6). So *Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:06:25 CST* is the same as *Fri, 28 Nov 2014 09:06:25 UTC*. So You are receiving correct UTC timestamp.

From the question it is unclear if You wrote server, which is sending timestamps or not.

Anyway, to convert timestamps look at:

- `gmtime()` - interprests timestamp as UTC;
- `localtime()` - interprets timestamp as local time (takes into account time zone)
- `tzset()` - change timezone used by `localtime()` (and few other functions)

Also, if You need parsing of time in string representation, `strptime()` may help (just keep in mind zone names/meanings may be different or missing on different OSes).